# How to convert user input text to programming text in python 2?

Tags: python, function, user-input

So I was writing a function for Euler's Method for solving first order differential equations. My problem is that I have to change the code every time I want to change the differential function.

Is it possible to have the user input an expression and then get the program to use that input to carry out a calculation?

```
def derivative(a,b):
    func=a**2+b**2
    return round(float(func),4)

def euler(x_in,y_in,x_fin,step):
    rounder = [x_in,y_in,x_fin,step]
    for i in rounder:
        i=round(i,4)

    x=x_in
    y=y_in

    while not(x==x_fin):
        der=derivative(x,y)
        x=round(x+step,4)
        y=round(y+(der*step),4)



    print y
```

I would like to be able to change the func variable in the derivative function on user input.

Comment: What about `eval`?

Comment: Regardless of everything else, rounding the intermediate results is a horrible idea.

Comment: Rookie programmer here. Didn't about the function. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @DYZ If I don't round them, they do this thing where the 10th or such decimal has a value. float(5)=5.00000000001 or something like that, didn't know any other way of getting around it.

Comment: What if the user enters `"__import__('os').system('echo allurbasearebelongtous')"`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I think it's traditional to use less dangerous commands, like 'echo "delete all files"` or something.

Comment: Or, [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). "DO DONT" is an interesting command, @juanpa.arrivillaga :P

Comment: @roganjosh haha yeah, just liter-loled when I read it

Comment: Floating point numbers are imptecusr. When you round intermediate results, you make them even more imprecise.

Answer (score 0):

ive had this problem today and got it to work using a dictionary.

What I did is:
1st step, defining functions:

```
def hello():
print('Hello')
```

2nd step, defining dictionary:

```
func_dict = {'goodbye':hello}
```

3rd step, asking for command:

```
command = input('Goodmorning Sir.')
```

4th step, asking for the translation of input to output (goodbye->hello in this case, you can also use the same words):

```
func_dict[command]()
```

Hope this was clear enough, ill put my full code below (from a different code though) if you want to see an example.

thanks DYZ for editting at first glance.

```
def test():
    print('Test is successfull')

def help():
    pass

func_dict = {'test':test,'help':help} # In this case the 1st is the input, 2nd output
command = input('> ')
func_dict[command]()
```

EDIT: Maybe using .int or .float will be better in this case.